# Adding default properties to Select Options with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

lets say I have this select menu and options in angular, if I want to add some sort of an array associated with each of them so for example if someone choose
"Man Haircut" so the client side will know automatically that the price is 10$, duration is 30 min and some sort of a description.

```
        <tr>
            <td>Service</td>
            <td><select type="text" ng-model="product.service" 
                    ng-options="product.service.text for product.service in objectList track by product.service.Main Haircut">
                <option value="Man Haircut">Man Haircut</option>
                <option value="Woman Haircut">Woman Haircut</option>
                <option value="Hair Dye">Hair Dye</option>
                <option value="Abu Agela">Abu Agela</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

fullCalendar select function being used to fetch startTime from the calendar

```
select: function(start, end) {
            // Booking Form Toggle
            if ($('#bookmenu').css('display') === "none") {
            $('#bookmenu').show();}
            // Fetching data from click event to booking form
            $("#startdateID").val(moment().format(start));
        },
```

what I'm trying to achieve here is generating the end date based on the service selected by the user based on the start date.

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you are trying to ask, since you used both an array of `product.service` and a static group of options in the same dropdown.  However. in general, what you are describing is exactly how `ng-options` works, assuming each `product.service` has a `text`, `price`, `duration`, and `description` property. The extra `<option>` elements seem redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: ill be honest i'm a complete beginer when it comes to angular and JS in general, this is a job interview project i have been asked to do and I learned everything from scratch, so I have no idea how to use the Angularjs select configuration.

Comment: the documentation for the API at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select is pretty thorough and has an example that is very similar to what you are trying to accomplish; have you tried examining the plunker of their provided examples?

Comment: This is really a very simple task for angular to achieve, and you were already using some of the angular syntax.  I think some of my confusion here is twofold; what exactly isn't working the way you want (you didn't provide any expected vs current results), and why you would ask how to take angular and rewrite it without angular.  Honestly, this is something that can be done in a couple lines of code with angular, but takes a lot more effort in jQuery.

Comment: well the problem ill have afterwards is I need to manipulate the duration of the service in some calculation using jQuery and if ill use scope to reach that data I have no idea how I can do it. if you are intrested to see what I have dont so far and what is the exact purpose of this I dont mind sharing it with you for further enlightments :D

Comment: It still feels like you aren't truly embracing angular here.  Why would you need to use jQuery *specifically* to manipulate the data?  jQuery is only a library to communicate with the DOM, the same as angular is;  any calculations would be just plain JavaScript, and wouldn't be jQuery specific.....

Comment: let me edit and add the function that fetch the onClick event from the fullCalendar to the question.

Comment: seems like that just looks for a ui element with the `startdateID` `Id` value, so you should just be able to populate that in your UI from your angular data.  That being said, what about using an angular directive for fullcalendar, like https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar?

Comment: I have less then 24 hours to finish this project and I have been working on it for a week now, changing the entire jquery into the fullcalendar ui will consue a lot of time and I have tried it, its completly broken on certain function - the selct function for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model='scope_product' ng-options='product as product.text for product in object_list'></select>

<script>
$scope.scope_product;

var object_list = [
  {text: 'Man cut', price: 10.00, duration: 30},
  {text: 'Woman cut', price: 20.00, duration: 1200}
]
// then you can access the selected option using $scope.scope_product
// so to get price $scope.scope_product.price
</script>
```

Comment: Might have to change my title, but is there any chance you can show me an example of this being done with jQuery?

Comment: @DanielNetzer don't mix jQuery with Angular;  not only does it make the code needlessly complex, it also requires extra work to make both frameworks play nicely together.  This is something that is already built in to the angular framework and doesn't need outside libraries.

Comment: I know but at the moment the only thing thats realy using Angular is my REST service while the fullCalendar plugin i'm using is 100% jQuery so I thought once everything is done I can just migrate my REST to jQuery if I have the time to do it.

Comment: Hey angular requires jQuery and they work together to some extent. Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/s4kq6uar/

Comment: @DanielNetzer well then it seems like you are asking the wrong question to the wrong tag,  If you don't plan on using angular in your final project.

Comment: will edit the title right away. sorry for the confusion and I appreciate the help.